# Need some clarity over this

Tags: c, operators, bitwise-operators

```
unsigned char Flags;
```

What value get stored each step in Flag, if Flag has default value on power up i.e 0?

```
Flags |=0x04;  //Flags =      What will be stored here?
Flags &= 0xfe; //Flags =      What will be stored here after bitwise operation?
```

What does this if statement does?

```
if(Flags & 0x01)  
{
  //When will it enter into this conditional?
}
```

Comment: Flags cannot have a null value or a nothing value. Did you mean 0?

Comment: Yes. The default value on Power up.

Comment: It would be checking last bit i.e if it is `0` or `1` .

Comment: Please edit the question.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "default value on power up" for a variable in C.

Answer (score 2):

If `Flags &= 0xfe` is the last operation before `if(Flags & 0x01)`, the expression will always be `false`, so the conditional will not be entered.

This is because `0xfe` mask is `11111110`<sub>2</sub>, and `0x01` mask checks the least significant bit, which will always be zero.

Answer (score 1):

In binary values:

```
unsigned char Flags; // Flags = ????????;

Flags |=0x04; // Flags = ?????1??

Flags &= 0xfe; // Flags = ?????1?0
```

Then `if(Flags & 0x01)` is always `false` with whatever initial value.
because `?????1?0` & `00000001` is `00000000`

Comment: You should add an initialisation to `someValue` for `Flags`, to avoid possible misunderstanding with respect to undefined behaviour.